# Chainlink VRF requestRandomness returning a requestId of 0

Tags: solidity, chainlink, vrf

Would it be possible for Chainlink VRF's `requestRandomness(bytes32 keyHash, uint256 fee)` method to return a value of `0` as the request ID? I'm not sure if the VRF returns incremental request IDs.